# Install specific version of dnx

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

I work on an ASP.NET 5 project which was set up using dnx/k version 1.0.0-beta3. Recently I did a clean install of my OS and VS and lost beta3 packages, I have only beta4 installed. Is it possible to install specific version of dnx?
I have already tried:

`dnvm install 1.0.0-beta3` etc.

Comment: Did running that command give an error or was there no output at all?

I've been reading through the powershell script that executes the command (https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/blob/dev/src/dnvm.ps1) and it seems that calling the command the way you have would execute on line https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/blob/dev/src/dnvm.ps1#L1102

You might need to pass in a specific Architecture and Runtime to install that specific version (although it defaults to x86/clr). Maybe try that?

Comment: I tried specifying an architecture as well as a runtime version every time getting the same error (404). Possibly previous releases are no longer available on dnvm service.

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of things here. One of them is which feed settings you have. Run `dnvm` to list those like below:

```
   ___  _  ___   ____  ___
  / _ \/ |/ / | / /  |/  /
 / // /    /| |/ / /|_/ /
/____/_/|_/ |___/_/  /_/
.NET Version Manager v1.0.0-beta5-10375
By Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc.
usage: dnvm  []

Current feed settings:
Default Stable: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Default Unstable: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2
Current Stable Override: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v2
Current Unstable Override:
```

If the version you want to install is available on the stable feed, run the below command:

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-beta4-11566
```

This installs 1.0.0-beta4-11566 from the active stable feed. If you want to install a specific version from an unstable feed, add `-u` switch:

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-beta4-11566 -u
```

Comment: I don't have feed settings listed running my dnvm (it is beta4, maybe it is available starting from beta5 builds).

Comment: where do you locate the specific versions that are available for download/install?

Comment: @tugberk the older versions of dnvm don't have an upgrade-self command (arguably the ones that need it the most).  Trying to install dnvm again results in it not installing new version because dnvm already exists (another stupid design).  Luckily one can get around that by deleting the existing dnvm and running the install script to get the latest version.